# Webpack webpackChunkName magic comment does not work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, code-splitting, react-loadable

I am trying to use react loadable and dynamic import to split code to multiple bundles. The split process works very well. However, when I try to use the magic comment `webpackChunkName` to let Webpack customize the bundle names, it always name my bundles like 0.bundle.js 1.bundle.js ....

I used `chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js'` in my `webpack.config.js` and also explicitly put "`comments: true`" in my .babelrc

After a whole day's research, I really feel frustrated. Really appreciate if someone has a clue.

Here is my configuration

**webpack.config.js**

```html
entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
```

**.babelrc**

```html
 {
  "presets": [
    ["env", {"modules": false}],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread", "react-hot-loader/babel", "syntax-dynamic-import", "dynamic-import-webpack"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
      ],
      "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread", "dynamic-import-webpack"]
    }
  },
  "comments": true
}
```

**Router file**

```html
const Login = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'LoginContainer' */ './containers/LoginContainer'),
  loading: LoadingAnimation,
});
```

**The building result:**

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If I use const Login = r => require.ensure([], () => r(require('./containers/LoginContainer')), 'LoginContainer');  It will work appropriately. Not sure whether I drop the comments somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:
The library's author gave a lot of support for looking for the solution. It turns out I used both dynamic-import-webpack and react-imported-component/babel in the .babelrc. After removed dynamic-import-webpack, it works very well with import()**

---

Please try the method above first.
Found the solution. 
I used the import() in my router, which does not work with webpackChunkname comment.
After **I changed it to System.import()**, the comment can be used by Webpack.

Hopefully, other people who have the same issue can see this.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Also for the others who use eslint, remember to put `"System": true` inside the field `globals` (in `.eslintrc`) to avoid `undef` errors

Answer (score 1):

adding this part in my config file has fixed my issue:

`chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',`

Comment: In particular, this goes into the `output` part of the `webpack.config.js`.